# Linux: Support File Operations

Tags: linux, filesystems

Has someone maybe a good source where all available file operations like fopen, fread, mkdir, etc are described? When I am googleing for Linux file operations most pages explain me how the filesystem hierarchy looks like.

Comment: linux or unix system call is different of stio function. What are you looking for ? open, close, unlink, write etc ... or fopen, fwrite, fread etc ... ?

Answer (score 5):

The functions you're asking about actually fall under several categories - file stream I/O (`fopen`, `fread`, etc.), lower-level file descriptor I/O (`open`, `read`, etc.), and filesystem/directory manipulation (`chown`, `mkdir`, etc.).

For an overview of file stream I/O functions, see [`man stdio`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdio).

For searching Google, try "posix file api" instead of "linux file operations."

You can also check the [GNU C Libary Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html):

- [Input/Output on Streams](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html#toc_I_002fO-on-Streams)
- [Low-Level Input/Output](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html#toc_Low_002dLevel-I_002fO)
- [File System Interface](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html#toc_File-System-Interface)

Answer (score 4):

I 'm not sure if this helps, but this is directly out of the kernel source:

```
struct file_operations {
    struct module *owner;
    loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t, int);
    ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
    ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);
    int (*readdir) (struct file *, void *, filldir_t);
    unsigned int (*poll) (struct file *, struct poll_table_struct *);
    int (*ioctl) (struct inode *, struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
    int (*mmap) (struct file *, struct vm_area_struct *);
    int (*open) (struct inode *, struct file *);
    int (*flush) (struct file *);
    int (*release) (struct inode *, struct file *);
    int (*fsync) (struct file *, struct dentry *, int datasync);
    int (*fasync) (int, struct file *, int);
    int (*lock) (struct file *, int, struct file_lock *);
    ssize_t (*readv) (struct file *, const struct iovec *, unsigned long, loff_t *);
    ssize_t (*writev) (struct file *, const struct iovec *, unsigned long, loff_t *);
    ssize_t (*sendpage) (struct file *, struct page *, int, size_t, loff_t *, int);
    unsigned long (*get_unmapped_area)(struct file *, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long);
};
```

Filesystems generally register all their implementations to these callbacks.

Comment: These are lower level than you'll often want.  Some of these functions don't seem to be accessible from userland, and as a userland developer, you'll often be using functions like fopen and fread that are implemented in libc rather than the kernel.

Comment: Yeah, probably got a little carried away. But at least it contributes to the answer in some small way :)

Answer (score 1):

Yep -- use the man pages. `man fopen`, `man fread`, `man mkdir`, etc., will describe the usage of those functions. Many man pages also have a "See Also" section that will direct you to the man pages of related functions, sort of like a primitive Wikipedia. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to have an overview over all the existing linux file system functions like fopen, fread, mkdir, chown etc

Answer (score 1):

There a several file operations APIs on different levels of the stack, e.g. [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) API, [Standard C AP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)I, [Linux VFS API](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/vfs/vfs.html) (as Jeremy mentioned), and the [FUSE API](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html). All the APIs do more or less the same thing, but the details are very different.

- *fopen* and *fread* are members of the standard C file (stream) operations. Links: [GNU Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#toc_I_002fO-on-Streams)
- *mkdir* is member of the POSIX file API. Links: [OpenGroup Definition](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/mkdir.html), [GNU Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#File-System-Interface)

These two APIs are the most important for the normal user.

A good book about the topic is "[Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment"](http://www.apuebook.com/index.html) by Stevens and Rago

Answer (score 0):

use `man 2 open` and `man 2 mkdir`. at the bottom of this man pages are the name of related command.

Alternatively, if you search a browseable version of this man pages, you can try [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)